# IBM Cloud Code Engine: How to check logs when app not active?

Tags: ibm-cloud, serverless, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I have deployed an app to IBM Cloud Code Engine. It has the [minimum instances configured to zero](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-app-scale), so truly serverless and only active on demand. Now I wanted to [check the logs from the CLI](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-view-logs#view-applog-cli) with

```
ibmcloud ce app logs --name myapp --all
```

it comes back with this message:

> FAILED No instances running for application 'myapp'. Verify that
> the application name is correct and it is running

How can I check the application logs after it has run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code Engine application (and job) logs can be seen once [Application Logging has been enabled](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-view-logs#view-applogs-ui). The logs are then available in a separate [IBM Cloud Logging dashboard](https://cloud.ibm.com/observe/logging).

I also found this [old blog post exlaining how to enable CLI access to those logs](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/search-logdna-records-from-the-command-line). After enabling it I was able to retrieve the app logs using my CLI / development environment.

[image: show JSON log records on CLI]

Depending on what I am after, I am using one of these three lines to get to the log data / lines:

```
python3 searchLogDNA.py myconfig.json 12 "search term" | jq
```

for pretty printing, or

```
python3 searchLogDNA.py myconfig.json 12 "search term" | jq "._line"
```

to extract the actual log line from the record, or

```
python3 searchLogDNA.py myconfig.json 12 "search term" | jq "._line | fromjson`"
```

to turn the string with JSON data in the log line to actual JSON output.